# Stored Procedure gives out two sets of unwanted data

Tags: sql-server, validation, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure to validate a user(login), everything is working except for when the user enters an email which is NOT registered. You see I have handled that exception wherein if the count of email address in the table is 0,it should give out:

```
  Select 0 as AccountLocked,0 as Authenticated,0 as RetryAttempts,0 as Registered
```

and if it is not 0, it will execute the next steps.The problem is when the enter an email which is not registered, it gives me back two sets of results which are as below:

```
  Select 0 as AccountLocked,0 as Authenticated,0 as RetryAttempts,0 as Registered
```

and

```
 Select 1 as AccountLocked,0 as Authenticated,0 as RetryAttempts,1 as Registered
```

The complete proc is given for reference.What am i missing here? why is it giving me the second result too which I don't want?

```
Alter proc spValidateUser
    @EmailAdd nvarchar(30),
    @Password nvarchar(20)
as
begin
    Set Nocount on;
    Declare @UserId nvarchar(10),@LastLogin datetime,@RoleId int,@AccountLocked bit,@RetryCount int,@Count int

    Select @Count=Count(EmailAdd) from tblAllUsers
    where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd
    if(@Count = 0) begin
        Select 0 as AccountLocked,0 as Authenticated,0 as RetryAttempts,0 as Registered
    end else
        Select @AccountLocked=IsLocked from tblAllUsers where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd

    ----if account is already locked------
    if(@AccountLocked = 1) begin
       Select 1 as AccountLocked,0 as Authenticated,0 as RetryAttempts,1 as Registered
    end else begin
        -----check if username and password match-----
        Select @UserId = UserId, @LastLogin=LastLogin, @RoleId=RoleId
        from tblAllUsers where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd and Password=@Password
          ----if match found--------
        If @UserId is not null Begin
            Update tblAllUsers
            SET LastLogin= GETDATE(),RetryAttempts=0 WHERE UserId=@UserId

            Select @UserId [UserId],
            (Select Role from tblRoles where RoleId=@RoleId) [Roles],0 as AccountLocked,1 as Authenticated,0 as RetryAttempts,1 as Registered
        End Else Begin
            ------if match not found--------
            Select @RetryCount=ISNULL(RetryAttempts,0) from tblAllUsers where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd

            Set @RetryCount=@RetryCount+1
            if(@RetryCount<=3) Begin
                ----if retry attempts are not completed------
                Update tblAllUsers Set RetryAttempts=@RetryCount where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd

                Select 0 as AccountLocked,0 as Authenticated,@RetryCount as RetryAttempts,1 as Registered
            End Else Begin
                ------if retry attempts are completed--------
                Update tblAllUsers Set RetryAttempts=@RetryCount,IsLocked=1,LockedDateTime=GETDATE()
                where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd

                Select 1 as AccountLocked,0 as Authenticated,0 as RetryAttempts,1 as Registered
            End
        End
    End
End
```

Edit: Looks like it is executing the below code too :

```
 Begin
      ------if retry attempts are completed--------
      Update tblAllUsers Set RetryAttempts=@RetryCount,IsLocked=1,LockedDateTime=GETDATE()
      where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd
      Select 1 as AccountLocked,0 as Authenticated,0 as RetryAttempts,1 as Registered
      End
```

but why should it execute the above when the emails don't match?

Comment: With not registered email ... you mean the emailid doesn't exist in table?

Comment: @Rahul- Yes! Unregistered email address.

Comment: Formatted the code so that you'll better understand what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your procedure logic a bit like below

```
        if exists(Select 1 from tblAllUsers where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd)
           Select 0 as AccountLocked,0 as 
           Authenticated,0 as RetryAttempts,0 as Registered
        else
           Select 1 as AccountLocked,0 as Authenticated,
           0 as RetryAttempts,1 as Registered
```

Comment: AccountLocked has nothing to do with it,i have a different logic for AccountLocked.The logic that i have implemented is simple.If Email exists in the table,go ahead with next steps.If email address is not found in the table just give out                                                         Select 0 as AccountLocked,0 as 
           Authenticated,0 as RetryAttempts,0 as Registered

Comment: Your logic for accountlocked in absurd. If email doesn't exists then no need checking that extra if condition. This is what i could simplify it to. You can follow along the line.

Comment: Yes,thats what i am trying to do.I dont want the code to go anywhere once it has found that the email does not exists.That is exactly my logic too.

Comment: `Select @Count=Count(EmailAdd) from tblAllUsers where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd` this query @count will be 0 if email id doesn't exists and so the next `if(@Count = 0)` will pass. So changed it to use `exists` rather.

Comment: Can you paste the entire code here after implementation of EXISTS? I am not able to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is here:

```
Select @Count=Count(EmailAdd) from tblAllUsers
where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd
```

Now the @count will be zero, and you'll return 0 as AccountLocked in following if:

```
if(@Count = 0) begin
    Select 0 as AccountLocked,0 as Authenticated,0 as Retry...
end else
    Select @AccountLocked=IsLocked from tblAllUsers where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd
```

This was just else, no begin + end block here.

Here you'll check if account is locked, but since it wasn't found @AccountLocked is still NULL

```
----if account is already locked------
if(@AccountLocked = 1) begin
   Select 1 as AccountLocked,0 as Authenticated,0 as Retry...
end else begin
```

Now you're here checking password, even though user wasn't even found, so this will never find anything:

```
    -----check if username and password match-----
    Select @UserId = UserId, @LastLogin=LastLogin, @RoleId=RoleId
    from tblAllUsers where EmailAdd=@EmailAdd and Password=@Password
      ----if match found--------
    If @UserId is not null Begin
   ....
```

And then the second result set comes from here:

```
    End Else Begin
        ------if match not found--------
```